# Istio helm installation using helm

Tags: istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

I am trying to install istio related helm charts (base/istiod/gateway) in a single helm chart using dependency chart.

```
apiVersion: v2
appVersion: 1.17.3
description: Helm chart for deploying Istio gateways
icon: https://istio.io/latest/favicons/android-192x192.png
keywords:
- istio
- gateways
name: gateway
sources:
- http://github.com/istio/istio
type: application
version: 1.17.3
dependencies:
  - name: base
    version: 1.17.3
    repository: https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
  - name: istiod
    version: 1.17.3
    repository: https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
```

But proxyv2 image in gateway deployment was set to auto which will be updated during runtime.

```
image: auto
```

I have hardcoded the image and set to `image: "{{ .Values.global.hub }}/{{ .Values.global.proxy.image | default "proxyv2" }}:{{ .Values.global.tag }}"`

```
global:
hub: docker.io/istio
tag: 1.17.3
proxy:
  image: proxyv2
```

Now pods are getting crashloopbackoff. below was the pod log (kindof showing man page).

```
Istio Pilot agent runs in the sidecar or gateway container and bootstraps Envoy.

Usage:
  pilot-agent [command]

Available Commands:
  completion           Generate the autocompletion script for the specified shell
  help                 Help about any command
  istio-clean-iptables Clean up iptables rules for Istio Sidecar
Use "pilot-agent [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```